# How to create .htaccess file that redirect short links into html files?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, short

How to create `.htaccess` file that redirect short links into html files?
Eg.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/start$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html [L]
```

The above rule gives me a `404 error`. I have my `index.html` in the main folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of leading slash. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^start/?$ /index.html [L]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Stupid mistake, but how much valuable :)
Is there a way to redirect www.mydomain.pl to www.mydomain.pl/start too?